# Best Method for Jar Extraction in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jar

How do you extract the contents of a JAR file in (Ubuntu) Linux?

Comment: How is this at all Linux-related? You use the exactly same method in any other OS.

Comment: yous hould always select the right answer. Thats the way the site works

Answer (score 63):

Fun fact: A .jar file is actually just a .zip file

```
unzip file.jar
```

Comment: Not work for `stanford-chinese-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar` at  http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml

Answer (score 39):

```
jar -xvf file.jar
```

Comment: it says "it does not look like a tar archive"

Comment: `jar -xvf file.jar tofolder`

Comment: What package (in my case, on ubuntu/wheezy) supplies the jar command?

Comment: @lindes If you are using ubuntu/debian, simply `apt-get install fastjar`

Comment: Does nothing on CentOS. `$ sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/bin/jar -xvf gs.jar 
$ ls
gs.jar`

Answer (score 7):

or if you have jdk installed:

```
jar xf file.jar
```

Comment: Does nothing on CentOS. `$ sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/bin/jar xf gs.jar 
$ ls
gs.jar`

Answer (score 2):

For a GUI viewer use:

```
file-roller file.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

```
unzip -o GST_Build.jar -d
```

TRY THIS ONE TO EXTRACT A JAR FILE IN LINUX

Comment: these oneliners should be in comment, if u want to answer then it should explain how it works for a better understanding of OP and future reference seekers

Comment: Please, don't shout, i.e., do not use all capitals.